# Is it possible to retrieve a stash after running git filter-branch?

Tags: git, git-stash, git-filter-branch

I ran `git filter-branch --env-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE'` to fix the commit dates after I rebased. However, I didn't know that my stash would be lost.

I've tried the following:

- running `git reflog --all`, checking out the earliest commit that it showed (`c9e4e26 HEAD@{37}: rebase (start): checkout e3536c9^`) and running `git stash list`
- running `git fsck`, checking out every unreachable/dangling blob and commit and running `git stash list`

Is there a way to retrieve that stash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your existing stash is not exactly *lost*.  Well, it's hard to find, so in that sense, it's "lost".  What has happened is that `git filter-branch` has *damaged* it.  What `git stash` does is make two, or sometimes three, commits, with the key one looking like a merge commit.  Most Git commands treat it *as* a merge.  That includes `git filter-branch`.  This can damage the stash-group since `git stash` itself demands these oddly-formed clumps of commits—they look like merges, but can't be treated as merges.

Since nothing in Git can actually *change* any existing commits, though, what filter-branch did was copy the stash to new and "improved" (but actually, damaged) commits.  The name `stash` now refers to these new and unimproved (deproved? depraved?) commits.

If you have not clobbered all the `refs/original` space:

```
git update-ref refs/stash refs/original/refs/stash
```

will restore `refs/stash` to the way it was before the filter-branch operation.  (This assumes a single pass of `filter-branch`; each additional pass would require `-f` or deleting the previous `refs/original/` space, either of which destroys the value you wanted to get back here.)

If you were using the stash "stack", that's in the reflog for `refs/stash` itself.  It should be undamaged except that the last entry, `stash@{1}`, should hold the old value of `refs/stash` from before the filter-branch operation.  That provides another means of recovery, if you *have* clobbered the `refs/original` names.  If you ran multiple passes of `git filter-branch`, you may need a higher number than `1` here.

If all else fails, the `git fsck` method described in [the `git stash` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), near the end under **Recovering stash entries that were cleared/dropped erroneously**, is available, but painful.

(Incidentally—not that this helps at *this* point—this is one of many reasons I recommend *avoiding* `git stash` most of the time.  Since all it does is make commits, just make normal commits.  The rest of Git will deal nicely with these normal commits.)